# how do you change a active class in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

i have a navigational bar at the side of my website but the problem is that when i change the tab in the navigational bar the active class does not change here is my code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color:yellow">

<font color="red"><div align="center"><h1>About</h1></div></font>
<head>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #875050;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="prodject.htm">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="prodject1.htm">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="prodject2.htm">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="prodject3.htm">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my java script code

```
$(".nav li").click(function() {
    if ($(".nav li").removeClass("active")) {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    }
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

is there any way to fix this

Comment: First, stop using deprecated HTML, which will interfere with your CSS. `<font>` is no longer valid and all styling should be done with CSS. Next, write valid HTML. The `head` element comes before the `body` and you don't place `div` or `h1` elements in the `head`.

Comment: You might start with valid HTML. The font element is obsolete, a head element can't be inside a body element. You can't have two bodies in a single page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the HTML is invalid and obsolete.

Comment: rob jun they are the same things but one may last longer i don't think you should try to close it because i am using older code.And they both do the same thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have `nav` class in HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li><a class="active" href="prodject.htm">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

You don't need `if`, directly use selector with the method.

```
$(".nav li").click(function() {
    $(".nav li.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

---

OR,

```
$(".nav li").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a nav class in your dom tree. Add to ul element class attribute with nav value:

```
<ul class="nav"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure you also have the class attribute for those a tags but also maybe you target the a tag and not nav li

```js
$("a").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings("active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have added `nav` class to `ul` tag use this code `<ul class="nav"></ul>` and make changes in jquery use below jquery code.

```
$(".nav li").click(function() {
    $(".nav li.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```